# Jackson JSON, REST Data Binding & HashMaps problem

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I implemented a RESTful web service with Spring and am using Jackson JSON as the serializer / deserializer for JSON objects.

However I run into Error 415's when the object that is to be deserialized contains a HashMap:

```
private Map<String, String> requestMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

If I remove this, everything works perfectly. Is this a known issue? Are there any fixes?

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: You get a 415 if Jackson doesn't support serialization of the object. Can you expand your question to show a more full example of the class that contains the map?

Comment: @skaffman .. here is the class https://gist.github.com/919959 .. it also has public getters and setters

Comment: I don't see any `Map` in there.

Comment: It is commented out, line #17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Jackson serializes from Interface-type references just fine.  The following demonstrates this point.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Map<String, String> requestMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    requestMap.put("one", "1");
    requestMap.put("two", "2");

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(requestMap));
    // output: {"two":"2","one":"1"}

    List<UserPermission> userPermissions = new ArrayList<UserPermission>();
    userPermissions.add(new UserPermissionImpl("domain1"));
    userPermissions.add(new UserPermissionImpl("domain2"));

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(userPermissions));
    // output: [{"scope":"domain1"},{"scope":"domain2"}]

    Container container = new ContainerImpl(requestMap, userPermissions);

    // From an Interface-type reference, where the implementation is an object with two Interface-type references:
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(container));
    // {"requestMap":{"two":"2","one":"1"},"userPermissions":[{"scope":"domain1"},{"scope":"domain2"}]}
  }
}

interface UserPermission {}

class UserPermissionImpl implements UserPermission
{
  public String scope;
  UserPermissionImpl(String scope) { this.scope = scope; }
}

interface Container {}

class ContainerImpl implements Container
{
  public Map<String, String> requestMap;
  public List<UserPermission> userPermissions;

  ContainerImpl(Map<String, String> requestMap, List<UserPermission> userPermissions)
  { this.requestMap = requestMap; this.userPermissions = userPermissions; }
}
```

There's some other problem in the system you're using.

Comment: That maybe correct. I'm not really sure, this thread is a few months old and I've shifted projects so I can't test it on that code base, but I'll play around when I have time. :-)

Comment: Spring and Jersey add funny things to JSON handling.  There are a few things that require special configurations in order to get default Jackson behavior.  If you do ever happen to figure out what's going on, do please post an update.  I'm sure I'm not the only curious one.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the problem. Jackson JSON has difficulties with Interfaces. So in the definitions, use HashMaps and ArrayLists instead of Maps and Lists. Not sure if this is a perfect solution, but it works for me.

Comment: "Discovered the problem. Jackson JSON has difficulties with Interfaces." -- Do please elaborate.  What difficulties with interfaces does Jackson have?  What specifically is the problem you discovered?  Is a corresponding issue logged at the Jackson project site?

Comment: Not sure if the bug is logged or whether it is a bug at all. I mean it won't deserialize a List but will deserialize as ArrayList.